# $2$ out of $4$ points, each of distance at most $1$ apart, are at most $1/\sqrt2$ apart

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Given $4$ points in the plane such that any pair of them are a distance of at most $1$ apart, show that some pair of them must be of distance at most $1/\sqrt{2}$  apart.

I figured the solution might involve a pigeonhole argument, but as my geometry is rusty I'm having trouble turning the "distance of at most $1$" condition into a condition that bounds all $4$ points in a region that can then be subdivided into $3$ regions in which every point must be within $1/\sqrt{2}$. Or that might be entirely on the wrong track.

Comment: Note that in the optimal configuration, at least one pair of points is distance $1$ apart. If no pair were, the configuration could simply be scaled up until the largest distance is $1$. This constrains the other two points to be within the intersection of two circles of radius $1$ drawn on the first pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given answers give excellent visual representations of what's going on, but I think I stumbled upon the kind of argument I was looking for:

**Claim:** Given $4$ points in the plane, $3$ of them must either be collinear or form either a right or an obtuse triangle.

*Proof:* Consider the convex hull of the $4$ points.

If it is a segment, then there are $3$ collinear points.

If it is a triangle, say $ABC$, then the point in the interior of this triangle, say $D$, forms three different triangles with the other three points whose angles at $D$ add up to $360^\circ$, meaning that at least one of these triangles is right or obtuse.

Finally, if the convex hull is a quadrilateral, its angles also add up to $360^\circ$, so at least one of its angles must be right or obtuse, giving a right or obtuse triangle.

---

But if three of the points form a right or obtuse triangle $XYZ$ with obtuse angle $Y$, then $XY^2 + YZ^2 \leq XZ^2$. If $XY$ and $YZ$ are both greater than $1/\sqrt{2}$, this would make $XZ > 1$, a contradiction. So there is always a pair of points at most $1/\sqrt{2}$ apart.

Comment: +1 Best argument.

Comment: The triangle argument works even if one of the points lies on the side of the triangle. So the statement can be strengthened to "all four are collinear or there are three that make a non-acute triangle."

Answer (score 0):

By eyeballfrog's comment, if there's an arrangement of four points such that all pairwise distances lie in the interval $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1]$, then by scaling, we can guarantee that two are a distance $1$ apart. Let these points be $A$ and $B$. The diagram shows circles of radius $1/\sqrt{2}$ and $1$ with centers $A$ and $B$. The remaining two points must be in the curvilinear regions $CDEF$ and $C'D'E'F'$, excluding the inner arcs of radius $1/\sqrt{2}$.

They can't be in different regions, as $ACBC'$ is a square with side-length $1/\sqrt{2}$, so $CC' = 1$, and between any two points in different regions there is a vertical distance of at least $CC'$.

But they can't be in the same region either. The triangle $ABE$ is equilateral, so $EC = \sqrt{3}/{2} - 1/2$. Applying the law of cosines to the triangle $ABD$ gives $$AD^2 = AB^2 + BD^2 - 2 AB \cdot BD \cos \angle ABD.$$ As $AB = BD = 1$ and $AD = 1/\sqrt{2}$, this gives $\cos \angle ABD = BG = 3/4$ and thus $DF = 1/2$ (because $DF \parallel AB$). Therefore, $CDEF$ can be contained in a rectangle with sides through $C, D, E, F$ and parallel to $CE$ and $DF$. This rectangle has diagonal length $\sqrt{CE^2 + DF^2} < 1/\sqrt{2}$, so all points in $CDEF$ (and, by symmetry, $C'D'E'F'$) are closer than $1/\sqrt{2}$.
[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Bear with me.

Okay...  So two points $A$ and $D$ must be the furthest (or tied for furthest) apart. Say they are $d$ apart and $d \le 1$.  We might as well assume they are exactly $1$ apart; everything we calculate will be in terms of that distance.

I drew the following image Based on $A$ and $D$:

[image]

The Black circles are centered at $A$ and $D$ and have a radius of $1$ (or $d$).  And the red circles have a radius of $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$.  (As $\frac 12 < \frac 1{\sqrt 2} < 1$ we know the red circles intersect.)

The points $e$ and $f$ are where the circles of radius $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ intersect.  And $g$ is are the lines $ef$ and $AD$ intersect.

The geometry you need to know is that $\triangle Aeg$ and $\triangle Afg$ are congruent right triangles and by the Pythagorean theorem that $eg^2 + Ag^2 = Ae^2$.  But $Ae=\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ and $Ag = \frac 12$ so .... $eg = \frac 12$.

That means the distance from $e$ to $f$ is $1$.

Well... so?

Well where can we put $B$ and $C$?

Well we can't put them outside the black circles.  That'd mean they are more than $1$ away from both $A$ and $D$.

We can't put them in the blue areas because that would mean they are more than one away from either $A$ or from $D$.

We can't put one of them in a light green area the other in the other light green area because that would mean they are more than $1$ apart from each other.

If we put either $B$ or $C$ in a lavender or in the yellow area that would mean that point is within $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ of either $A$ or $D$ and our result would be fullfilled.

The only unconsidered option is that both $B$ and $C$ are place in the same light green area.  Then they'd both be more than $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ for $A$ and $B$ but they'd be pretty close to each other.

How close?